# Web browser control doesn't display html file correctly

Tags: c#, html, css

This is a launcher I coded a while ago. I wanted it to have a Web browser which opens a certain website (html) which can be edited through FTP.

But it looks different:

Launcher:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

I can't find the error.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Awakening</a>
    </div>  

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Register <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Vote</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">

        </li>
      </ul>


    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a lot of information, but by default the WebBrowser control uses IE7 compatibility. IE7 probably doesn't understand a lot of the CSS you've used. You can try editing the compatibility meta tag as outlined [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility/) to try and use a more up to date renderer.

Comment: Thanks that helped :)